# Slightly bitter potatoes or onion

Tags: potatoes

I have got the same annoying result a few times now, when making potato gratin, and something known as "french potato cake" in my country (grated potato in frying pan).

I believe that it's the potato which has a slightly off taste; bitter/metallic/raw. Some googling leads to solanine as an explanation, but I'm not completely satisfied.

Things that might be related:

1. I rarely peel them (yet, I think that the same batch of potatoes, used a few days apart did taste fine the first time).
2. I *think* that it's worse when any piece of potato isn't in direct contact with heat (i e the center of a thick potato cake or gratin)
3. I almost always add raw, finely grated onions.
4. Sometimes raw garlic - my impression is that it makes it worse.
5. The potatoes are *not* green, at all, in any of these circumstances.

So my guesses are:

1. Solanine, in that case solution is to peel them?
2. Something related to oxidation, either in garlic/onion or perhaps catalysed by it. Solution, in that case?
3. Rawness - can potatoes be soft and still be "raw"?

Comment: For solanine, you'll see a layer of green under the skin.  You want to remove all of the green bits.  You also want to remove the areas around sprouted eyes, not just the sprout itelf.

Comment: Oh, they're not green and don't have sprouts (updated question).

Comment: Did you grow these potatoes yourself? If so, were they well-watered throughout the growing season? I've found that if I under-water my potatoes, they turn out somewhat bitter. I started growing my own because I ran across too many potatoes with a bitter, musty or chemical smell/taste, so if you have commercial potatoes, any of dozens of contaminants or additives could cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut tells me that they are either under-done or need to be rinsed. Have you tried par boiling the  potato? I would try slicing the raw potato, boiling for a few minutes to draw out some of the starch - then rinsing them before adding to your recipe. Worth a try I think.

Good luck!